# Are homosexuals more prone to violence?

Tags: sexuality, aggression

A wiki entry on [Conservapedia on "Homosexuality and murders"](https://www.conservapedia.com/Homosexuality_and_Murders) states:

> Dr. Eckert wrote regarding homosexual murders the following: "Equally high is the number of homicides, many probably related to transient attachments, which often lead to suspicion, jealousy, and murder. When murder does occur it is exceptionally brutal with an overkill appearance... Overkill, as it is seen in homosexual and lesbian murders, is certainly a form of sadistic crime. In these instances multiple stabbing and other brutal injuries...are common findings..."[6]

Dr. Eckert's background is claimed to be the following:

> According to the New York Times, Dr. William Eckert was a world-renowned authority in the field of pathology and he worked on major murder cases including the assassination of Senator Robert F. Kennedy and the Charles Manson murders.[4] Dr. Eckert founded the American Journal of Forensic Medicine and Pathology.[4][5] According to Time magazine, Dr. Eckert was a pioneer who encouraged collaborative effort between law-enforcement and forensics teams.[5]

I should point out however that in recent years numerous studies have shown that the police have not been very kind to the LGBT community and with interactions with the police very poor and full of bias. For example, consider this urban.org article ["“No Cops at Pride”: How the Criminal Justice System Harms LGBTQ People"](https://www.urban.org/urban-wire/no-cops-pride-how-criminal-justice-system-harms-lgbtq-people).

So, I wonder if these sources are biased against homosexual couples.

Comment: Referring to your question title, you originally wrote: "That is the basic claim of this site [conservapedia.com]". I had two main concerns: (1) you didn't explicitly mention the source, which already indicates a biased point of view; (2) the quote you provided made no such claim. Out of context, it is unclear what "equally high" is referring to, and the remainder of the quote does not state homosexuals are more prone to violence. The claim would be "**When murder does occur** it is exceptionally brutal ...".

Comment: Your interpretation thus seemed biased towards homosexuality. :) I edited out these concerns, as I find the remainder of the question on-topic, and I appreciate you providing a source for your statement. Welcome to Psychology & Neuroscience!

Comment: Can you also add a date when this claim was made? The cases in the background (Kennedy, Manson) suggests that he's talking about the situation 50 or 60 years ago when the legal situation of homosexuality was very different, so just from that it's dubious how relevant it is for the situation today or even can be generalised.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen I didn't realize that he was quoting from 50 years ago. I should've figured that [internalized homophobia](http://homoresponse.blogspot.com/2011/06/mental-health-and-substance-abuse.html) is a factor that they do not consider

Comment: I was also thinking of selection bias of the police. At the time when homosexual people could not be open about it, many couples did not live together or perhaps pretended to be friends in a shared flat or something similar, so when police investigated some murder they may not even have realised it was a relationship murder but perhaps classified it as an argument between (heterosexual) friends about money or something. So there is a possibility that the police connected only the more horrific cases with homosexuality.

Comment: Also, if police (like most people) didn't have an idea how many homosexual people live a peaceful life and they only see the murders, statements like "high is the number of homicides" are very dubious as they don't know what to compare it with.

Answer (score 2):

**Science Advances**

A study conducted by Science Advances confirmed what researchers already believed, and that is that LGBTQ people are nearly four times as likely to become victims of violent crime compared to non LGBTQ people.

[Science Advances](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aba6910)

> We find SGMs disproportionately are victims across a variety of crimes. The rate of violent victimization for SGMs is 71.1 victimizations per 1000 people compared with 19.2 victimizations per 1000 people for those who are not SGMs.

**Domestic abuse**

Also it has been reported that homosexual men and women face a high risk of becoming violently victimised by their very own partner, with 47.5% of lesbians and 29.7% of gays reporting having been victimised by their partner.

[NCBI](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9403987/)

> This study explores gender differences in victimization and perpetration experiences of gays and lesbians in intimate relationships. A sample of 283 gays and lesbians reported on their experiences both as victims and perpetrators of gay/lesbian relationship violence by completing a modified version of the Conflict Tactics Scale (Straus, Gelles, & Steinmetz, 1980). General results indicate that 47.5% of lesbians and 29.7% of gays have been victimized by a same-sex partner.

**Are homosexuals more prone to violence?**

According to a study LGBTQ people are nearly four times as likely to become a victim of violence than that of a non LGBTQ person, and homosexuals face a high risk of becoming a victim of domestic violence to their same sex partner.

Comment: What is the percentage of heterosexuals that get victimized by their partner? Without that information, it is hard to grasp what "disproportionate" means.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris. Rather than find a study, which I cannot find, I have changed the wording.

Comment: Is internalized homophobia a factor for the domestic violence?

Comment: @JacobBlaustein Are you for real? How can be the cause when **the violence is occurring within the homosexual relationships?**

Comment: *becoming violently **victimised** by their very own partner* - Interesting word choice, which deliberately avoids the question. If homosexuals are more likely to be violently victimized by their homosexual partner - which wasn't the question - then yes, **homosexuals are in fact more prone to violence (against their partner)** - which was the *actual* question. Thanks for answering the question.